# Persiting a state machine context in HttpSession java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineContext

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I have created a `StateMachinePersist` implementation to persist the StateMachineContext y HttpSession:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class SessionStateMachinePersist(private val session: HttpSession) : StateMachinePersist<States, String, String> {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun read(contextObj: String): StateMachineContext<States, String>?  {
        val stateMachineContext = session.getAttribute("${session.id}-$contextObj") as StateMachineContext<States, String>?
        logger.debug("Session {} has state machine context {}?", session.id, contextObj, stateMachineContext != null)
        return stateMachineContext
    }

    override fun write(context: StateMachineContext<States, String>, contextObj: String) {
        session.setAttribute("${session.id}-$contextObj", context)
    }
}
```

When it is going to persist the `DefaultStateMachineContext` it throws the following exception since the `DefaultStateMachineContext` isn't serializable: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineContext`

How can I use a StateMachineContext implementation that is serializable?

Comment: What's the use case of that? Why would you want to couple SM context with HttpSession?

Comment: I have a state machine associated to a session scope (there's one instance per logged user): https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/#sm-scopes I've had to externalize the HttpSession to a remote cache using spring-session and that approach fails since StateMachine can't be serialized. According to state machine doc (https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/#sm-persist-statemachinecontext) we can use a persister to persist the StateMachineContext.But it is also failing with the serialization error for the DefaultStateMachineContext

Comment: I see - I was just wondering why not use the userId as a shared identifier between HttpSerssion and SM Context and thus avoid the need to put the SM context inside HttpSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to make the State Machine Context serializable and persist it in the Http Session:

**SerializableStateMachineContext**

```
class SerializableStateMachineContext<S, E>(var id: String?, var childs: List<StateMachineContext<S, E>>?, var state: S?,
                                            var historyStates: Map<S, S>?, var event: E?, var eventHeaders: Map<String, Any>?,
                                            var extendedState: SerializableExtendedState?) : Serializable {

    constructor() : this(null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

}
```

**SerializableExtendedState**

```
class SerializableExtendedState(var variables: Map<Any, Any>) : Serializable {

    constructor() : this(mutableMapOf())

}
```

**SessionStateMachinePersist**

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class SessionStateMachinePersist(private val session: HttpSession) : StateMachinePersist<States, String, String> {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun read(contextObj: String): StateMachineContext<States, String>? {
        val stateMachineContext = session.getAttribute("${session.id}-$contextObj") as SerializableStateMachineContext<States, String>?
        logger.debug("Session {} has state machine context {}?", session.id, contextObj, stateMachineContext != null)
        return DefaultStateMachineContext(stateMachineContext?.childs ?: mutableListOf(), stateMachineContext?.state, stateMachineContext?.event,
                stateMachineContext?.eventHeaders, DefaultExtendedState(stateMachineContext?.extendedState?.variables ?: mutableMapOf()), stateMachineContext?.historyStates)
    }

    override fun write(context: StateMachineContext<States, String>, contextObj: String) {
        val serializableExtendedState = SerializableExtendedState(context.extendedState.variables.toMap())
        val serializableStateMachineContext = SerializableStateMachineContext(null, context.childs, context.state, context.historyStates, context.event, context.eventHeaders, serializableExtendedState)
        session.setAttribute("${session.id}-$contextObj", serializableStateMachineContext)
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you have to operate with the state machine you just have to restore it, execute the trigger operation and persist it, e.g.:

```
    @PostMapping(value = ["/process-input"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @ResponseBody
    fun processInput(session: HttpSession, @RequestBody projectCreationInput: ProjectCreationInput, model: ModelMap, status: SessionStatus) {

        val stateMachinePersister = buildStateMachinePersister(session)
        stateMachinePersister.restore(stateMachine, "myid")

        ...

        triggerStateMachineExecution(projectCreationInput, event, status)

        ...

        stateMachinePersister.persist(stateMachine, "myid")

    }

    private fun buildStateMachinePersister(session: HttpSession): DefaultStateMachinePersister<States, String, String> {
        val stateMachinePersist = SessionStateMachinePersist(session)
        return DefaultStateMachinePersister(stateMachinePersist)
    }
```